# How to retrieve the sorted amount using DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I store data to my firebase like this where the amt has years under it. And under the years has the months. Then under the months has amount.

```
uid1 > uid: uid1
     > amt:
       > 2021
         > 12
           > 500
       > 2022
         > 1
           > 100
         > 2
           > 50
uid2 > uid: uid2
     > amt:
       > 2021
         > 1
           > 250
         > 5
           > 5
uid3 > uid: uid3
     > amt:
```

How will I retrieve these information of uid with it's corresponding value for certain month. I wanted to use DocumentSnapshot but I don't have an idea if this is possible. Thanks!

```
For January 2022
uid2: 250
uid1: 100
uid3: 0

For February 2022
uid1: 50
uid2: 0
uid3: 0
```

Comment: By following this structure you can only access one document at a time.

Comment: Hmm, any suggestion on the structure so that I can access it multiple documents at a time?

Comment: I might have an idea now. The document will be the combination of year and month. Then the fieldname is the uid and the value is the amount. If I fetch the document, I will manage to get all the uid along with its corresponding amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you just want to retrieve a specific value for a specific month or build a widget with this data using a FutureBuilder. But to get the data use:

```
var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME).doc(SPECIFIC_UID);
var data = await documentReference.get();
var monthValue = (data.data() as Map)['amt'][SPECIFIC_YEAR][SPECIFIC_MONTH];
```

As an example for the uid1, year 2021 and month 1:

```
var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME).doc(uid1);
var data = await documentReference.get();
var monthValue = (data.data() as Map)['amt']['2021']['1'];
```

Also follow [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read) link to the official Flutter Firebase docs for more info!

Comment: I actually wanted to build a list of sorted table (order by amount) containing the list of uid and its amount. I plan to load it first to a list then show it. I will try this, thanks!